# wordpress custom sidebar in services pages

Tags: wordpress, service, sidebar

I'm trying to the different sidebar for different services pages on my site. My theme was created from scratch by some guy.

**single-services.php**

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

how can I do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the recommended use of this function:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar-id-name' ); ?>
```